# Creating a Enum ButtonSet in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script

I often use Browser.msgBox() and Browser.inputBox() when making programs in Google Apps Script. They can have different [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set)'s and I want to make my own, with custom labels. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do so. However, instead of a msgBox or inputBox, you can write your own UI and display the UI.